# How can I get common response format for Lambda API?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am using Node.js for AWS Lambda + API Gateway APIs.

I have multiple Lambda functions and each giving different response formats as it integrated multiple third party SDKs like Stripe/DynamoDB and all.

Is there any way to get common response for all the functions like below?

```
{
  "success" : true,
  "data" : { RESPONSEFROMLAMBDA },
  "messages" : null,
  "code" : 200,
  "description" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The third-party services your Lambda functions are using shouldn't have any bearing on the response format. You just need to update all the API Gateway endpoints to use a mapping template with this format.

Comment: Can i create one common Mapping Template and apply the same to get above response?

Comment: Yes you could do that

Comment: Can you guide me or send any reference to get above response?

Comment: Here is the guide to using mapping templates http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html.

   You can folllow the petstore example which uses mapping templates http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-from-example.html.